# Como ver el dato de una columna oculta de Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Como ver los datos de una columna que se oculta, pero necesito desplegar el contenido en un `texbox` que esta al costado del `datatable`.
A continuación tengo el `datatable` configurado para ocultar la columna.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 3 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
} );
} );
```

Luego para recuperar los datos de la fila seleccionada utilizo la siguiente función:

```
 $(function() {

   $('#example tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClick);
    });

 function rowClick()
 {
   if (hlr)
      $("td:first", hlr).parent().children().each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('markrow');});
   hlr = this;
   $("td:first", this).parent().children().each(function()
   {
      $(this).addClass('markrow');
   });
   var valor= $("td:eq(3)", this).text();
   //añadiendo el valor a un textbox
   $("#textbox").html(valor);
 }
```

El problema consiste, en que si lo oculto la columna, ya no muestra el valor de la columna 3 sino el de la siguiente columna 4.

Comment: Amigo, sería de mucha apoyo que brindes mayor información y así brindarte una respuesta enriquecida de información. Te recomiendo des un vistazo a [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites tu pregunta para podamos apoyarte.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el selector `:visible` para seleccionar sólo aquellos elementos  visibles. Después concatena tu selector :eq() para obtener el elemento en la posición que indiques.

```
var valor = $('td:visible', this).eq(3).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el elemento esta invisible jQuery no lo encuentra, prueba acceder al valor mediante el api de de datatables:

```
var valor = dtTable.row(this).data()[3];
```

para esto al crear el datatables asignale un nombre q sirva de referencia:

```
dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
...
```

Código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>datatablesvaloroculto</title>
<style>
.markrow{background:#fe0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
        <th>Columna 4</th>
        <th>Columna 5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
        <td>Row 3 Data 4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
<div id="textbox"></div>
</body>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    });
});


$(function() {
    $('#example tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClick);
});

function rowClick()
 {
     $(this).parent().find('tr').removeClass('markrow');
     $(this).addClass('markrow');

      var valor = dtTable.row(this).data()[3];  
      $("#textbox").html(valor);
} 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

var valor = dtTable.row(this).data()[3];
$("#textbox").html(valor);

para solucionar este problema simplemente agrega el nombre de la columna por ejemplo:
var valor = dtTable.row(this).data().nombreColumna;
$("#textbox").html(valor);